# how to send multiple emails using sendgrid and and also edit header for website name

Tags: php, email, header, sendgrid, cc

I am trying to use send grid as an email platform for my php but the problem is I cannot send multiple emails as a CC header and also I cannot edit the FROM header to display a Name in front of the email address.

```
$from = "News Letter <new@gmail.com>" // cannot get the "News Letter" to Display
$cc = array("aaaaaa@gmail.com","bbbbb@gmail.com");// doesnt send to arrays

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => $to,
    'cc'        => $cc,
    'subject'   => $subject,
    'html'      => $body,
    'from'      => $headers
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some additional fields in your $params array, like so:

```
$params = array(
  'api_user'  => $user,
  'api_key'   => $pass,
  'to'        => $to,
  'toname'    => 'Newsletter Person',
  'cc'        => $cc,
  'subject'   => $subject,
  'html'      => $body,
  'from'      => $headers,
  'fromname'  => 'Newsletter'
);
```

Sendind directly via the Mail.Send endpoint does not allow for an array in the CC field, however if you use the [SendGrid PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) then you [can use and array for CC](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#setccs)